# load all data on single page load

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax, json

hi I have to create a website that load the data when page load so that website works without again redirecting it to server. that means when person open the website then only all the data is load and and then no post back is perform till user refreshes the url.

but using this methodology make the loading of the website very slow can anyone help me out how i can speed this process or increase the speed on my website

I have created this website in asp.net framework 3.5

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @SpencerRuport its just like i want to make single page webiste which contains lots of data to display on it

Comment: @SpencerRuport so when i fetch all the data from database the system get too slow i want to speed the fetching process

Comment: so your "generic" question is "how can I make my site load faster?".  I cast my vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a couple of guesses he is storing large amounts of data as arrays in his JavaScript for the site and trying to manipulate the DOM without a post back... Seems unlikely that this is being done without understanding AJAX / JSON, but I am guessing that is the answer he is looking for.

Basically: if you want a pattern which allows you to update the page without post-backs, and you don't want to pre-populate the data because there is too much, then you use AJAX.

Comment: hi matthew yes your near to my point can u just give reference url or sample code for this

Comment: Google 'AJAX Examples' or the like - there are tons of tutorials out there and frameworks for exposing the server side endpoints in every language. Given that you tagged ASP.NET, try here: http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/

Comment: how these toolkit site will help me out \

Comment: how this toolkit site will help me out

Comment: The best answer I can give is find some beginner tutorials and walk through them to learn the technology. At that point you will likely be in a position to ask a more specific question which people can help with. Good luck! - The link has a long list of examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the data using Javascript on page load. This does not require a post back, but does change how you load the data. You would need to create some form of service to consume with Javascript, but the page load would happen immediately.

In the end you are at the mercy of what you are trying to load. I would suggest first trying to tune that.

Comment: hi I already minimized the data to a minimum level i can reduce or tune it more and can u give refernce url where it is implemented or sample code as an example which explain me more

Comment: You should add that in your question or pose a new more specific question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly. It sounds like there are a couple options:

1) Dont use one page and fill it with an enormious amount of data. Try splitting the information into other pages. If there is a lot of data you are querying for a single page then yes it can take a while, especially if you are talking about thousands. but I don't know the size of your data set.

2) Some kind of paging...For instance showing the first 20 in a result then click a button to get the next 20, and so forth.

Loading a lot of data on a single page can be dangerious for the end user. I am not very familure with it but pagify.js may be something to look at.

Also AJAX and JSON is something very usefull.

Comment: hi this my biggest problem i have to use single page only

Comment: Highly recommend Ajax then...look into some jQuery examples.

Answer (score 0):

you are essentially asking how to load 100mb like it was 100kb. cannot be done. if you have a lot of data to show to the user, no matter how you get it, or cache it in your html page the response data going back to the browser will always be large. sorry but what you want is not possible. either change your design and load data segments when the user needs to view them, or reconsider the whole use of your page